# SAS script works in windowing environment but fails in Linux

Tags: linux, sas

The code works very good, and creates the data, but in Linux it says the the data has 0 observations.
It has to search in library the files with specific name (and date in name).

```
%let path=library.name;
%let fname=name.starts.with;



data fnames;
  length
  fref $8
  fname $200
  datestr $17
;
format fdate yymmdd10.;
rc = filename(fref,"&path.");
did = dopen(fref);
 if did ne 0
 then do;
  do i = 1 to dnum(did);
    fname = dread(did,i);
   if index(fname,"&fname.")
     then do;
      datestr = scan(scan(fname,-2,"."),-1,"_");
      date = input(substr(datestr,1,8),yymmdd8.);
      fdate = substr(datestr,1,8);
      output;
    end;
  end;
  rc = dclose(did);
end;
rc = filename(fref);
keep fname fdate;
run;

proc sort data=fnames;
by descending fdate;
run;

data _null_;
set fnames (obs=1);
call symputx("fdate",fdate,"g");
run;
```

How can I run the code in Linux? Why is it not read the data correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: There are no observations because either dopen failed, or there were no files.  Most likely dopen failed because the path specified was incorrect for Linux.  What is the actual path used?  You can debug the flow by using `msg=sysmsg(); putlog msg;` after the statements with `filename` and `dopen`.  What does the log show?

Comment: The code also has some other issues.  You defined FDATE as numeric and try to assign a string value to it.  Your value for &FNAME seems to imply you want to test if the filename starts with that string, but your test is instead testing if that string appears anywhere in the filename.

Comment: @Richard the log shows that the data “fnames” has 0 observations and 2 variables